# Scan with quotes in filter throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, hbase, thrift, happybase

I'm using Happybase/python to get data from hbase and I already used some filtering, but now for some reason it won't work.

I have the filter for my scanning code goes like that :

```
f = "SingleColumnValueFilter ('input', '', =,'substring:{}')".format(keywork)
res = pTable.scan(reverse=True,limit=1000, filter= f.encode('utf-8'))
```

Which btw works Now this `input`column has records like this :

```
"{'institution_id': '023', 'application_id': '01', 'channel_id...}"
```

the problem is that if I set `keyword` to lets say:

```
keywork = "instition_id"
```

it works, but obviously that's not what I need, so when concatinate it with the value I'm looking for :

```
keywork = "instition_id': '"+ my_value
```

I get `thriftpy.transport.TTransportException: TTransportException(type=4, message='TSocket read 0 bytes')`

After new tests I conclude that the problem is with the single quotes, but I don't know why or how to fix it.
I tried `keywork = "instition_id\': \'"`, `keywork = 'instition_id\': \''` none of that worked. It's probably some thing silly but it driving me crazy.

And I'm thinking about regex, maybe I'll give it something like `institution_id?: ?my_value` with `?` to tell it any character would do fine but I don't know nothing about regex so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good thing you thought about regex, I don't know why it doesn't work even with escaping the quotes (I hope someone who knows would explain that to us), but here is something to get you going:

```
f = "SingleColumnValueFilter ('input', '', =,'regexstring:.*institution_id.: ." + your_value + ".*')"
```

the `.` means any character so the quotes won't trigger an error this time.
I'm also a beginner with regex so I expect anyone to refine, edit that line.

Comment: This worked for me, I tried to avoid regex since I'm not good at them but here we are, thanks a lot.